# Can I copy the Supreme logo design but use a different word?

Tags: copyright

I made a supreme style sticker with the same colors and font except with a different word and I just used an example for this one. Is this legal?

Answer (score 0):

As long as it’s a different word and different color you will be fine. You can reference their copyright on their website. But the logo is copyright for that specific color and name etc